# How to use Jenkins file parameter in Pipelines

Tags: file, jenkins, parameters, upload, workspace

My Jenkins pipeline runs on the Slave using agent `{ node { label 'slave_node1' } }`.

I use Jenkins file parameter named `uploaded_file` and upload a file called `hello.pdf`

My pipeline contains the following code

```
stage('Precheck')
{
  steps {
       sh "echo ${WORKSPACE}"
       sh "echo ${uploaded_file}
       sh "ls -ltr ${WORKSPACE}/*"
```

Output:

```
/web/jenkins/workspace/MYCOPY
hello.pdf
ls: cannot access /web/jenkins/workspace/MYCOPY/* No such file or directory
```

As you can see no files were found on the slave WORKSPACE.

Can you let me understand if I'm checking for the uploaded file in the correct location i.e under WORKSPACE directory?

How can I get the file uploaded to the slave's WORKSPACE?

I'm on jenkins version 2.249.1

Can I get this to work at least on the latest version of Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

So do you have a fixed file that that is copied in every build? I.e its the same file?

In that case you can save it as a secret file in jenkins and do the following:

```
environment {
    FILE = credentials('my_file')
}

stages {
    stage('Preperation'){
        steps {
            // Copy your fie to the workspace
            sh "cp ${FILE} ${WORKSPACE}"
            // Verify the file is copied.
            sh "ls -la"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: every user can upload a file of his choice using file parameter, so it will not be a fixed same file @Jan